# How to count all the nodes after a given node?

Tags: xpath

#### The Problem

I'm trying to count the number of distinct currencies in which a website displays prices.

The website's home page allows a user to select a currency from a drop-down list.

I'm trying to find an XPath expression that will count the distinct currencies in the drop-down list.

The list looks like this:

[image]

The first four currencies in the list are the currencies most often selected by users.

A complete list of currencies ordered by currency code is also displayed. The complete list contains duplicates of the first four currencies.

The 'popular' list and the 'complete' list are seperated visually by putting a disabled blank option in the drop-down list.

The HTML on the home page to create the list looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<select id="selCurrency" tabindex="122">
  <option value="GBP" selected="selected">Select your currency</option>
  <option value="GBP">GBP - £</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR - €</option>
  <option value="PLN">PLN - zł</option>
  <option value="USD">USD - $</option>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled"/>
  <option value="AED">AED - د.إ.‏</option>
  <option value="AFN">AFN</option>
  <option value="ARS">ARS - $</option>
  <option value="AUD">AUD - $</option>
  <option value="BDT">BDT</option>
  <option value="BGN">BGN - лв.</option>
  <option value="BOB">BOB - Bs.</option>
  <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

For brevity I've removed the elements that are not visible in the screenshot.

#### The attempted solution

The idea of my solution is to select just all the nodes that come after the blank separator and count them up.

This XPath expression selects just the separator:

```
//*[@id="selCurrency"]/option[@value=""]
```

According to the [w3schools page on XPath axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp), I can use the following-sibling axis to select all siblings after the current node.

Following the examples, I tried the following expression:

```
//*[@id="selCurrency"]/following-sibling::option[@value=""]
```

But this either returns nothing, or is illegal syntax. I'm not sure which.

How do I select all the nodes of the complete currency list and then count them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine your two attempts to get the right items:

```
//*[@id="selCurrency"]/option[@value=""]/following-sibling::option
```

If you then want to use XPath to count these, this would be the formula to count them:

```
count(//*[@id="selCurrency"]/option[@value=""]/following-sibling::option)
```

Comment: The first expression works fine in [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) and the [Simple Online XPath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/test). Opera Dragonfly automatically counts the number of nodes in the result, so I got my answer that way. The second expression produces no result in Opera Dragonfly and produces an error in the Simple Online XPath Tester. The error message reads: "java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.dom4j.Node". What tool did you use to test your expressions?

Comment: I didn't use a tool to test them; it's simply a fact that `count()` is a standard XPath function that returns the number of nodes in a node-set. Some tools and APIs are not designed to handle an XPath result that is not a nodeset, and this can be seen in the error message you got: the function is producing a numeric value ("Double"), but the tool is trying to cast the result to a `Node`, which produces an error.

Comment: I discovered XMLQuire, a .NET XML editor with a built-in XPath tester. It manages to evaluate Both expressions. In my example, the answer is 7.

Answer (score 0):

JLRishe already answered the presenting question.

Buried in the question text was a more general description of the problem:

> find an XPath expression that will count the distinct currencies in the drop-down list.

JLRishe's answer solves this problem but relies on the ordering of the elements. For someone used to working with sets, that just feels too fragile. The query would produce a misleading result if the interface designer removed the separator row, or chose to stop duplicating the 'popular' elements in the 'complete' list.

With [Dimitre Novatchev's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812762/111424), I came up with

```
count(/select/option/@value[not(. = '') and not(. = ../following-sibling::option/@value)])
```

It filters out the separator value and counts the distinct values that remain. When applied to my example, the output is

```
7
```

I believe this is a more robust solution to the problem I wanted to solve.