# Xpath getting multiple p tags in one nodeValue

Tags: php, xpath

I'd like to retrieve all of the p tags within `div class="post"` in one nodeValue. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="blogEntry expecting featured featured-post-today%e2%80%99s-top-story first">
<h2><a href="/2013/09/03/rachel-zoe-pregnant-expecting-second-child/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child">Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child</a></h2>
<div class="post">
    <p>Sometext</p>
    <p>someothertext</p>
</div>
<div class="blogEntry expecting featured featured-post-today%e2%80%99s-top-story first">
<h2><a href="someurl" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Rachel Zoe Expecting Second&nbsp;Child">sometitle</a></h2>
<div class="post">
    <p>Sometext</p>
    <p>someothertext</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my xpath:

```
$finder->query('//div[contains(@class,"blogEntry")]//div[@class="post"]//p');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be :

```
$finder->query('//div[contains(@class,"blogEntry")]/div[@class="post"]/p');
```

Comment: What do you mean with "still separating"?

Comment: its still separating `Sometext` and `someothertext` into separate nodeValues. I want `sometext` and `someothertext` in one value

Comment: Xpath just returns nodes from the document. And as they are separate nodes they will been returned as multiple nodes. You cannot "join" them. If you need to join their text values use PHP string operations after fetching the nodes, or xslt

Comment: _... obligatory mumbling that it should be_ `contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " blogEntry ")` _to avoid clashes with classes like `blogEntryContainer`_....

Comment: @Wrikken That's nice! :) Thx

Answer (score 1):

Very ugly but hope it is the one you are looking for -

```
//div[contains(@class,"blogEntry")]/div[@class="post"]/concat(p[1]," ",p[2])
```

or

```
//div[contains(@class,"blogEntry")]/div[@class="post"]/string-join((p[1],p[2])," ")
```

**output**

```
Sometext someothertext
Sometext someothertext
```

Comment: @jkushner Then I will think that way,no where in the post of OP it is being observed. I gave solution as per the post.