# Nesting in XPATH

Tags: count

I have the following XML data for which I would like create an `xpath` statement which i think might contain nested `count()`

Here is the XML data for 5 CD Rentals

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<DataBase>
  <!-- CD Rental 1 -->
  <Rental>
      <cd>
        <title>title1</title>
      </cd>
      <person uniqueID = "1">
        <name>name1</name>
      </person>
  </Rental>

  <!-- CD Rental 2 -->
  <Rental>
    <cd>
      <title>title2</title>
    </cd>
    <person uniqueID = "2">
      <name>name2</name>
    </person>
  </Rental>

  <!-- CD Rental 3 -->
  <Rental>
    <cd>
      <title>title3</title>
    </cd>
    <person uniqueID = "1">
      <name>name1</name>
    </person>
  </Rental>

  <!-- CD Rental 4 -->
  <Rental>
    <cd>
      <title>title4</title>
    </cd>
    <person uniqueID = "3">
      <name>name3</name>
    </person>
  </Rental>

  <!-- CD Rental 5 -->
  <Rental>
    <cd>
      <title>title5</title>
    </cd>
    <person uniqueID = "2">
      <name>name2</name>
    </person>
  </Rental>
  
</DataBase>
```

The `xpath` I had in mind was

```
Count the number of persons who rented multiple CD's
```

In the above XML data, the person with name as `name1` and the person with name as `name2` rented 2 CD's while `name3` only rented 1 CD. So the answer I am expecting is **`2`**. What could be a possible xpath for this?

Comment: what version of XPath is this? 1.0 or greater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible XPath expression would be:

```
count(//name[.=preceding::name][not(. = following::name)])
```

**<kbd>[xpathtester demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/eeaa30f4a68db310ca6e19958736219b)</kbd>**

Brief explanation about the expression inside `count()`:

- `//name[.=preceding::name]`: find all elements `name` which have preceding element `name` with the same value, in other words `name` with duplicate
- `[not(. = following::name)]`: further filter `name` elements found by the previous piece of XPath to return only the last of each duplicated `name` ([distinct in Xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812122/distinct-in-xpath))

Comment: hey, that absolutely works and tysm! but the syntax and logic are quite complex, do u mind editing your answer to have a much simpler xpath?

Comment: XPath 1.0 only provide limited functionalities, so that's the simplest I can think of