# Add a new namespace to a non root node in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I saw the post [XSLT : Add a namespace declaration to the root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055981/xslt-add-a-namespace-declaration-to-the-root-element)

The @StuartLC answer works. I need help ... in the example @schglurps... ¿How would  you add a new namespace to a non-root node?

The input XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="AcquisitionFolder">
            <Directory Id="dir2EE87E668A6861A2C8B6528214144568" Name="bin" />
            <Directory Id="dir99C9EB95694B90A2CD31AD7E2F4BF7F6" Name="Decoders" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And I'd want to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="AcquisitionFolder" xmlns:ns1="http://prerk">
            <Directory Id="dir2EE87E668A6861A2C8B6528214144568" Name="bin" />
            <Directory Id="dir99C9EB95694B90A2CD31AD7E2F4BF7F6" Name="Decoders" />
            <ns1:dir>prueba</ns1:dir>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

A new namespace in the node `DirectoryRef` (eg) `xmlns:ns1="http://prerk"`, it is a non root and copies all the same nodes.

I tried, but I couldn't find any suitable solution.

Could you please advise me?

Comment: Are you sure that's the result you want? What you show is not only changing the namespace of `DirectoryRef`. It is also removing the inherited namespace of its `Directory ` children.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: `DirectoryRef` remains in the default namespace despite the namespace prefix declaration appearing there, but you're right to question whether OP really has to have that declaration on `DirectoryRef`.  It can appear where used on the `dir` element or anywhere in the `dir` element's ancestry.

Comment: @kjhughes You are right.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you're rigth in that declaration site, i was wrong. The <dir> was in the imput. I need to add in the DirectoryRef because dinamically i need to add prefix to some nodes, eg <ns1:dir> and declare in the top node.. I think i have to edit the post

Comment: @kjhughes thanks i was wrong in the xml imput, i have to add in the DirectoryRef because dinamically i need to add prefix to some nodes, eg <ns1:dir> and declare in the top node. Im going to edit the post with my imput example. Please if you are help me

Comment: @BlasAM I have rolled back your question to what it was when I answered it. Please start a new question and post your significantly different problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the expected result using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef">
     <DirectoryRef xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:ns1="http://prerk">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <ns1:dir>prueba</ns1:dir>
    </DirectoryRef>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Though it might be simpler to do just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <ns1:dir xmlns:ns1="http://prerk">prueba</ns1:dir>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get a semantically identical result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="AcquisitionFolder">
      <Directory Id="dir2EE87E668A6861A2C8B6528214144568" Name="bin" />
      <Directory Id="dir99C9EB95694B90A2CD31AD7E2F4BF7F6" Name="Decoders" />
      <ns1:dir xmlns:ns1="http://prerk">prueba</ns1:dir>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Work it, but the namespace ns1 is added in the node, not in the top

Comment: @BlasAM I believe that with the 1st  stylesheet the namespace declaration will be added to the `DirectoryRef` start-tag - where you said you wanted it to be. However, this may depend on your processor. In general, such namespace declarations can be anywhere on the `ancestor-or-self` axis, and you shouldn't care where exactly your processor decides to put it.

Comment: yes, you're right ... I edited the post with my problem :). Thanks